# ctrlp :CtrlPTag search slow

Tags: vim, ctrlp

Im using ctrlp.vim and I'm trying to use the `:CtrlPTag` feature. I setup ctags using the instructions from this blog post:

https://blog.sensible.io/2014/05/09/supercharge-your-vim-into-ide-with-ctags.html

I've generated a ctags file for my Rails project and all my bundled gems using:

```
ctags -R --languages=ruby --exclude=.git --exclude=log . $(bundle list --paths)
```

The ctags file is about 13 MB.

When I try to run `:CtrlPTag` and just search for methods the search is very slow. Trying to type and delete the search text almost hangs vim completely.

Does anyone have any suggestions to speed up `:CtrlPTag`?

Note: I have tried to setup vimgrep to use 'ag' thinking that would be faster, but that hasn't helped. See: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/why-postgres-wont-always-use-an-index (I imagine this only helps with file searches)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to switch to `fzf`.

The default searcher for `ctrlp` using vimL, so is slow. However, `ctrlp` can use extensions implemented in `C` or other low level languages.

Since, `ctrlp` has been around much longer, it has a lot of extensions and pretty stable

Add this extension:

https://github.com/FelikZ/ctrlp-py-matcher

Comment: Wow, this is world's better than the default ctrlp search performance.  Thanks!  Bonus, in this report, there's a secondary readme on more speed improvements that can be made to ctrlp AND a note on the benefits of using silver searcher.  Awesome stuff!

Answer (score 5):

I hesitate to put this as an answer since it's sort of a non-answer, but you should consider [`fzf.vim`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) for searching tags. I had a similar problem with CtrlP, it was painfully slow on large tag files. `fzf` works pretty much identically to CtrlP for tags, except it can be orders of magnitude faster. Just install it with your package manager of choice and update the mapping you currently have for CtrlPTags with a mapping for `:Tags`:

```
" Search tags
nnoremap _ :Tags<CR>
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I've been looking for an excuse to use fzf. Upvoted! :)